# Print user input but add a new format or characters between the numbers ?

Tags: html, input, printing

I want to input numbers and print them like in the example bellow.

Input: 0000000000
Print with format: *0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*

I cant seem to figure it out with what i have read about formats in html.
If I can use something like:  $(this).formatCurrency({ symbol: '*',
to add in * between the numbers.

Would really appreciate any help or tips!

What i have so far is this

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="JavaScript">
       function showInput() {
       document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("user_input").value;
       }


 </script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p>*<span id='display'></span>*</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat like below:

```js
function showInput() 
 {

  var inp=document.getElementById("user_input").value;
  var hello='*';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    hello+=inp[i].concat('*');
  }

 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = hello;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all of the numbers and insert a "*" at desired position with `substr`

```js
var input = '000000000000000000000';
var newNumbers = input;

for (var i = 1; i < input.length * 2 - 1; i = i + 2) { 
    
    newNumbers = newNumbers.substr(0, i) + "*" + newNumbers.substr(i);  
}
alert(newNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split('')` to divide your input into single characters and `join('*')` to insert a `*` after each character:

```js
       function showInput() {
       document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("user_input").value.match(/.{1}/g).join('*');
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p>*<span id='display'></span>*</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you use regex to get the same result:

```
function showInput() {
       document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("user_input").value.match(/.{1}/g).join('*');
       }
```